# Highlight anchor link when user tabbs to link from a text input box

Tags: css, focus

I'm trying to get the background color of the "forgot password" text of a log-in form to change color, when the user tabs to it from the password text input field.

I've tried

```
#login-box a:focus, a:active
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

but the background color of the link is not changing when the user tabs to the link.

Comment: what element is the text? `label` `a` `p` etc?

Comment: It works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/Nkt5C/). Show us more of your code and your HTML structure.

Comment: its an anchor link `a`

Comment: Yes, I know, but if the code you're showing isn't working, there is probably somewhere else a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using `focus` and `hover`

```
a:hover {background:yellow; color:navy;}
a:focus {background:yellow; color:navy;}
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/s8Rdu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Had to make it a global style, not attached to any `.` or `#`

Comment: You shouldn't have to make it a global style.

Comment: You should post that and accept it so people will know to no longer submit answers.

Comment: The issue still exists in Safari, that it doesn't work for `:active` or `:focus`

Comment: You should post more of your code.  When it comes to anchors `<a>` pseudo selector order matters. `LVFHA: link, visited, focus, hover, active`.  Though I don't believe you have to place `focus` in the middle but should be the earliest placement.